# Matblazor MatNumericUpDownField format attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, matblazor

I am trying to use the format attribute of the MatNumericUpDownField without success. I have a French culture, and I want en-US formatting.
Looking for some advice on how to format an int. There is no example.

My current field:

[image: My current field]

I want 1.00 formatting.
My code :

```
<MatNumericUpDownField Label="@localiser["MaterialGroupFactor"]" 
 @bind-Value="@SelectedManufacturingActivity.MaterialGroupFactor" 
DecimalPlaces=2 Minimum="0" Outlined="true" Step="0.01m" Format="F"
Class="margin-top-5"></MatNumericUpDownField>
```

the right display:
@SelectedManufacturingActivity.MaterialGroupFactor.ToString("F",CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the field type is missing, so the control doesn't 'know' to display in a currency format.

Try to add this property:

```
FieldType="MatNumericUpDownFieldType.Currency"
```